# How to square the result of cfit?

Tags: matlab, object, curve-fitting, numerical-integration, function-handle

I'm using MATLAB for some data analysis of experimentally collected data.
After using the `envelop`e and `abs` functions I'm using the `fit` function to get the equation I'm after, which I need to square then integrate.

The code I have for getting the equation and integrating it is as below:

```
[yupper,ylower] = envelope(signal,1000,'peak');

dat = abs(yupper);

fitted = fit(x,dat,'linearinterp');

% Create a new function handle
fitted = @(x)fitted(x);

q = integral(fitted, 3e4,9e4,  'ArrayValued', 1)
```

To square the function I am using (used with and without the `.` in `.^`):

```
%square fitted
fitted = fitted.^2;
```

Where I'm struggling is when I try and square `f` before converting to function handle I get the error(s):

```
Undefined operator '.^' for input arguments of type 'cfit'.

Error in findenergyfromfitcurve (line 5) fitted = fitted.^2;

Undefined operator '^' for input arguments of type 'cfit'.

Error in findenergyfromfitcurve (line 5) fitted = fitted^2;
```

and when I convert to function handle then square I get the same errors for the function handle:

```
Undefined operator '^' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.

Error in findenergyfromfitcurve (line 10)
fitted = fitted^2;

Undefined operator '.^' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.

Error in findenergyfromfitcurve (line 10)
fitted = fitted.^2;
```

In short - how do I square the output of the `fit` function?

Comment: Please make sure that the code snippet you post contain the lines that give the error (as of now, this is not the case with `fitted = fitted.^2;`). Did you try the most basic form of numeric integration, which is evaluating your function at some fine grid, then multiplying the values by dx and summing? I bet it would work in your case.

Comment: Oh my apologies, I'll add that in now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would do the trick:

```
fsq = @(x)f(x).^2;
```

I expect this to work because you would be squaring **numbers** (the outputs of `f(x)`) and not function handles or cfit objects (the object `f` itself).

Comment: Instructions unclear - do you mean replace the line fitted = @(x)fitted(x); with that line of code?

Comment: @user2587726 Judging by your question the instructions seem pretty clear :) In addition to what you said, you should obviously put `fsq` in the `integral`.